How to Wrap Selected Text in a Custom Section Tag Using React-Quill?
I'm using React-Quill and I want to embed the text selected with my mouse into a section tag. For example, if I select with my mouse
<h1>title></h1><p>loream</p>

I would like to obtain this:
<section><h1>title></h1><p>loream</p><section/>

